# C# SQLite Generic Read method for CRUD implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite

Im refactoring a project that using SQLite.

For all CUD operation of CRUD I got the solution, but for the R operation I got some troubles.

I got some access like this

```
DBController.Instance.DB.Table<Cache<T>> ( ).Any ( cc => cc.CacheId == oId );
```

How can I rewrite this to get something like

```
public T Request(type,params)
{
    DB.Table<Cache<type>> ( ).params();
}
```

Is it even possible?

`Table<Cache<T>>` can be anytype of Object like `Person`, `Animal`, `Human`

Comment: You should introduce some strategy with generics hierarchy

Comment: I'm afraid that it's a little bite too complexe for my skills.

Comment: You can use a `<T>` parameter in a class definition, and inside that class use the `DB.Table<Cache<T>>` without any problems.

Comment: Trying this but got an error from SqlLite. I will show you this when I come back to home.